# How to get lastInserted Value on different field instead of ID when successfully insert

Tags: php, laravel-4

Good day,

There was a function on laravel where you can get last inserted ID using the `->insertGetId` command eg:

```
$insId = DB::table('time_log_tbl')
->insertGetId(array('uxid' => $user->xid, 'time_in' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s') ));

echo $insId; // e.g: 10
```

is there a function as well to get other fields like `name` or `address` instead of just ID? Thanks

I am using it to retrieve the value of `timestamp` to let the user know what time exactly was it recorded on the database.

Comment: Why you need return other field instead your primary key ?

Comment: I need to retrieve the time stamp

Comment: I just start learn laravel 5 too, but i think may be 'no', okay i wait to see best answer too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use last insert ID and  query the table for name, address column especially for that ID, something like this:

```
$id = last_insert_id();
$q = "select name,address from tbl where id=".$id;
```

Comment: ohh thanks for the answer sir @thepiyush13.. I also thought about the same first, I just wanted to clarify if there is another method thats more simple than to make another query :) I guess it not available

Comment: this is a good idea but using query is not good and is prone to sql enjection.Laravel has query builder that uses prepared statements and i think its better to use that feature.

Answer (score -1):

try this

For Pre-Laravel 4

```
$lastdata = DB::table('time_log_tbl')->order_by('upload_time', 'desc')->first();
```

For Laravel 4 and onwards

```
$lastdata = DB::table('time_log_tbl')->orderBy('upload_time', 'desc')->first();
```

Basically that will get the last row data which is the last inserted data but if you want to use the last inserted id then you can use the last inserted id with laravels built-in query builder.

```
$insId = DB::table('time_log_tbl')
->insertGetId(array('uxid' => $user->xid, 'time_in' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s') ));

$data = DB::table('time_log_tbl')->where('id', $insId)->first();
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: I guess this code is not that reliable since your not using an ID to get the exact data. just my opinion. thanks for the answer thought :)

Comment: I think for @melvnberd question is he insert data and get data from last row that he inserted.

Comment: @melvnber I have updated my answer. Please check it.